# GET-запрос. Вывод данных

Tags: php, json, get

Есть get запрос. В JSON выглядит так:

```html
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/v2/leads?status=20728261",
            "method": "get"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1601345,
                "name": "Тест",
                "responsible_user_id": 2600929,
                "created_by": 2600929,
                "created_at": 1531976544,
                "updated_at": 1531985130,
                "account_id": 20728252,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {
                    "id": 4573131,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4573131",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": {},
                "custom_fields": {},
                "contacts": {
                    "id": [
                        4573131
                    ],
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4573131",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "status_id": 20728261,
                "sale": 1300,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 1251568,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=1251568",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=1601345",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1620709,
                "name": "Тест2",
                "responsible_user_id": 2600929,
                "created_by": 2600929,
                "created_at": 1531985076,
                "updated_at": 1532061092,
                "account_id": 20728252,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {
                    "id": 4614393,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4614393",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": {},
                "custom_fields": {},
                "contacts": {
                    "id": [
                        4614393
                    ],
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4614393",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "status_id": 20728261,
                "sale": 2300,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 1251568,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=1251568",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=1620709",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Оттуда надо вытаскивать при обновлении страницы данные "name, account_id, tags, sale" Желательно один лид в одном блоке. 
Только начинаю учить PHP.

```html
<?php
$url = '#################';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['_embedded']['items'] as $item) {
    print $item['name'];
}
?>
```

В чем ошибка в данном коде? Не хочет работать

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj=Jsone_decode($data); 
$obg->нужное поле
```

Comment: <?php
$url = '###########';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['_embedded']['items'] as $item) {
    print $item['name'];
}
?>
Пытался так сделать неполучается

Comment: Естественно не будет работать, т. к. в item поля name нет, что php тебе и доложил... Почитайте про синтаксис json внимательнее документацию

Comment: Про vardamp почитайте, xdebug вообще топ будет и соизвольте внимательно прочесть возвращаемую ошибку, там написана причина ошибки