# GET запрос, вывод данных в блоки

Tags: php, json, get

Запрос GET выглядит так:

```html
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/v2/leads?status=20728261",
            "method": "get"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1601345,
                "name": "Тест",
                "responsible_user_id": 2600929,
                "created_by": 2600929,
                "created_at": 1531976544,
                "updated_at": 1531985130,
                "account_id": 20728252,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {
                    "id": 4573131,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4573131",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": {},
                "custom_fields": {},
                "contacts": {
                    "id": [
                        4573131
                    ],
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4573131",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "status_id": 20728261,
                "sale": 1300,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 1251568,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=1251568",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=1601345",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1620709,
                "name": "Тест2",
                "responsible_user_id": 2600929,
                "created_by": 2600929,
                "created_at": 1531985076,
                "updated_at": 1532061092,
                "account_id": 20728252,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {
                    "id": 4614393,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4614393",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": {},
                "custom_fields": {},
                "contacts": {
                    "id": [
                        4614393
                    ],
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/contacts?id=4614393",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "status_id": 20728261,
                "sale": 2300,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 1251568,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=1251568",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=1620709",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Пытюсь получить данные name и sale

```html
<?php
$url = '####/api/v2/leads?status=20728261';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['_embedded']['items'] as $item) {
    print $item['name'];
    print $item['sale'];
}
?>
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: какие ошибки пишет ?

Comment: @madfan41k в консоле гугла ничего нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [GET-запрос. Вывод данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857960/get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 0):

Сделай так:

`print_r( $json->_embedded->items );`

Допиши в вопросе. Если это пусто будет, сделай так:

`print_r( $json );`

Comment: Ничего не выводит
@user2736875 попробуй получить данные, вот для авторизации https://vils192.amocrm.ru/private/api/auth.php?USER_LOGIN=vils192@gmail.com&
USER_HASH=4983b90a5849e1e9e5732e0934dbe598974fc885 
, а это запрос: https://vils192.amocrm.ru/api/v2/leads?status=20728261